# Как в qt с помощью replace сделать подмену по типу regex $1$2

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt5, qregularexpression

В JavaScript операция подмены с regex

```
num = "11222333";
re = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
re.test(num);
num.replace(re, "$1,$2");
```

Как произвести подобное в Qt. Цель сделать замену унарных знаков на буквенные значения B -> (+) и C -> (-) и оставить знак стоящий перед унарным.

```
static QRegularExpression regex1("([+\\-*\\/^\\(\\)]|mod)([\\+])");
static QRegularExpression regex2("([+\\-*\\/^\\(\\)]|mod)([\\-])");
```

Попытался сделать как в JS:

```
qstr.replace(regex1, "$1B").replace(regex2, "$1C");
```

Но либо я выполняю её не коректно, либо она не доступна в Qt.

Comment: а там не \1 ? (но только писать нужно будет `"\\1C"`

Comment: @KoVadim.      Сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Qt используется другой способ (тоже популярный) - `"\1"`. Но слеши нужно экранировать, поэтому, нужно ещё один слеш.

```
qstr.replace(regex1, "$1B").replace(regex2, "\1C");
```